# Usage of gather/gathering

Tags: word-usage, passive-voice, participle-phrases

I'm bothered by the use of "gathering" in the following sentence:

"The initiative was originated at a regional-level meeting in Phuket in July last year, gathering telecom regulators from the 10 Asean countries."

(Source: http://www.bangkokpost.com/news/general/1202657/tourist-sim-tracking-plan-axed)

If it were up to me I would rewrite the sentence as follows:

- The initiative was brought up at a gathering of telecom regulators from the 10 Asean countries.
- Telecom regulators from the 10 Asean countries gathered in Phuket last year to hammer out the proposal.

or getting rid of "gather" altogether:

- The initiative was originated at a regional-level meeting in Phuket attended by telecom regulators from the 10 Asean countries.

I can't explain why, but the use of "gathering" in the original sentence doesn't seem right. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's grammatically correct, but it's not a very pretty or well-formed sentence.

"gathering telecom regulators" is a [participial phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/participlephrase.htm), describing something about the subject (which is *the initiative*), so it's saying that the initiative was gathering telecom regulators.

I think it sounds strange because the main clause is in the passive voice, and it's odd to say that *the initiative* gathered regulators, especially when the initiative was itself the subject of the passive voice, meaning that something else was originating the initiative.  Any of your versions actually sound a little better to me.